# Flexible www .htaccess setting causing Cross-Domain error AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, cross-domain, uri

I am making a very simple RESTful website using Angular 1.3.2.  It can be seen here:

http://artlyticalmedia.com

If you go to the same site with a leading "www" it will work because the .htaccess file rewrites the url without the www by doing this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem occurs if anyone were to try to deep-link with "www" in front, a la http://www.artlyticalmedia.com/portfolio (sans "www" works fine, try it).  If you take a look with your web inspector of choice you will see the cross-domain error being thrown for every `ng-include` template.  If it helps, here is my app.js file with all the routing:

```
angular
  .module('comartlyticalmediawwwApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ng.deviceDetector'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        navbarVal: 'home',
        title: 'Home'
      })
      .when('/portfolio', {
        templateUrl: 'views/portfolio.html',
        controller: 'PortfolioCtrl',
        navbarVal: 'portfolio',
        title: 'Portfolio'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl',
        navbarVal: 'contact',
        title: 'Contact'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        navbarVal: 'home',
        title: 'Home'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
  }).run(['navbarValChanger', function (navbarValChanger) {
    navbarValChanger();
  }]);
```

How do I fix this?  Do I change something in .htaccess or add a setting in app.js?  All the other similar questions deal with server-side queries, such as AJAX or using $https, when mine doesn't do that at all.  It is merely a route throwing the error when "www" is present so the other answers don't work.

Comment: *"I presume the issue is that Angular is capturing the URL before .htaccess removes the "www." "* If it's a redirect, that isn't possible. Angular won't run until the html/js reaches the browser, which will be after the redirect.

Comment: OK, I can remove that from my post in case it is misleading.  What other explanation is there for the error "http://artlyticalmedia.com/components/header.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.artlyticalmedia.com' is therefore not allowed access," where is clearly one address with "www" and one without.

Comment: Someone commented (I don't know where it went) that I should use a redirect instead of a rewrite, which I thought were the same thing (what would [R=301] mean besides "redirect 301").  How would a redirect be written differently and would it help?

Comment: I commented, and deleted it, because i don't know htaccess syntax well enough to know for sure. According to the docs, it looks like you are in fact redirecting.

Comment: Can you show how one of the ajax requests are being sent?

Comment: I see @KevinB, thanks for clarifying; I too know only a little of .htaccess and I read everywhere that it is a headache anyways.  What do you mean "show how one of the ajax requests are being sent"?  I am only using Angular ngRoute, which calls ngView functions so it should work.  You can see where in the horribly minimized vendor.js code this is happening in your inspector.  What else can I provide you?

Comment: I don't follow links in questions, so inspecting doesn't do much for me. What's failing for you is an ajax request to get a template then?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have some problems with the same-origin policy. Here is a nice [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) about it.
A possible solution for your problem (if I understand it correctly) is to change the origin with the following line at the beginning of your application:

```
document.domain = "www.artlyticalmedia.com";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.  I would also guess that I would need `document.domain = "artlyticalmedia.com"`, since that is what the rewrite directs to.  I tried both and neither worked.  Thanks for trying though.